# How to calculate sum of digits of a date in php?

Tags: php, date, sum

I've date in following format.

```
2019-02-27
```

I've to find sum of digits in above date. I've exploded the above value like this,

```
$date = '2019-02-27';
$dateArray = explode('-',$date);
```

Now date array will be like this:

```
array:3 [▼
   0 => "2019"
   1 => "01"
   2 => "02"
]
```

With 2 loops, I can get sum of all digits but if there any much better way or builtin function to do this ?

Any kind of suggestion or help is appreciated.

Comment: `any much better way or builtin function to do this`  -  Yes the imaginatively named - [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)  in your case `$total = array_sum(explode('-',$date));`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix it will return 2023 as output but output i want is 15

Comment: `15` makes no sense because that is `19-1-2` not a sum.

Comment: It’s not clear. From `2019-02-27` do you want 2 + 0 + 1 + 9 + 0 + 2 + 2 + 7 = 23?? If you could make your example consistent, I think it would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to split the date into separate characters and then [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) them. `array_sum` will ignore the `-` characters which are not valid numbers:

```
$date = '2019-01-02';
echo array_sum(str_split($date));
```

Output

```
15
```

Note that for your `$date` string of `'2019-02-27'` the correct result is `23`. `15` is the correct result for `'2019-01-02'` which is what your `var_dump` output says was the contents of your `$date` variable at the time.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix well if you're going to pull out the thermonuclear device you may as well use `preg_split('/(?=\d)|-/', $date, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` so the `-` characters don't make it into the array...

Comment: I actually thought about it, but alas I was too lazy... (o.O)>

Answer (score 1):

> With 2 loops, I can get sum of all digits but if there any much better way or builtin function to do this ?

Yes

```
 $total = array_sum(preg_split('//','2019-03-17'));
 echo $total;
```

Output

```
  23
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c92686e84e65bc617656afedc8b36c2a6c49c86)

Comment: it will return 2023 as output but output i want is 15

Comment: @SagarGautam - that wasn't clear in the question, but I updated.  Although 15 doesn't make much sense either.  Show me manually how you get a sum of `15` from those numbers.   eg.  1+3=4